# Meteor template, browser "cannot find module" imported

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app gives error on the browser console  `Cannot find module './body.html'`. Please see the image attached, after going over it many times and read some posts of similar issues, the problem still stands. Any idea what it is and how to fix it?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please we need a reproduction app. You can post it on Github and link it back here.

Comment: The browser shouldn't even see the import, I think. How are you starting your meteor app? Also, please post your `meteor list`.

Comment: Have you installed the `blaze-html-templates` package into your app?

Comment: Yes, version 1.2.1 is in the `meteor list` output.